# BupaR eventlot function doesnt take timestamp

Tags: r, timestamp

I am trying to use bupaR for process mining and on the eventlog function, the timestamp variable throwing error. I am using 24 hour date format in my datafile. my code is below
[image: 1]
the error is:

```
eventlog(eventlog = my_data, case_id = "Student_ID", activity_id = "Problem_Complexity", activity_instance_id = "Sr", lifecycle_id = "Status", resource_id = "Originator", timestamp = ”Timestamp”)

Error in UseMethod("timestamp") : 
  no applicable method for 'timestamp' applied to an object of class "c('POSIXlt', 'POSIXt')"
```

Or

```
mydates<-strptime(my_data$Timestamp, "%H:%M:%OS")
eventlog(eventlog = my_data, case_id = "Student_ID", activity_id = "Problem_Complexity", activity_instance_id = "Sr", lifecycle_id = "Status", resource_id = "Originator", timestamp = "mydates")
Error in eventlog.data.frame(eventlog = my_data, case_id = "Student_ID",  : 
  Timestamp classifier not found
```

I am new to RStudio too.